# Why does adding a ManipulationDelta event handler to an Image prevent scrolling?

Tags: windows-runtime

I'm encountering a problem while attempting to add functionality like pinch-zoom to an application that features an Image control inside of a ScrollView, which is inside a FlipView.  The Image control and ScrollView control are in the ItemTemplate of the FlipView.

The idea is that if the user pinch-zooms on the Image it will activate code which will create and display an enlarged version of the image in the Image control.  (The Image control in this case  contains a PDF page, so we want a bigger version of the PDF page, instead of just an enlarged and fuzzier view of the PDF page).

If I attach a ManipulationDelta event handler to the Image, it *will* catch ManipulationDelta events produced by the pinch-zoom gesture, which I can then use to create the PDF zoom effect.  However...now it will not catch scroll (drag?) gestures.  Or rather, these too get caught by the ManipulationDelta event handler.  I'd rather avoid having to implement code at this point to handle scrolling programmatically.  Do I have any options for somehow bubbling up (or "over"?) the ManipulationDelta events to whatever would handle the scrolling?  I would think this would happen already, the event would bubble up to the ScrollView which would then handle scrolling.  But it appears to not be happening that way.

I have e.Handled set to false in the ManipulationDelta event handler.  And the ManipulationMode on the IMage control is set to "All".  I've tried "Scale" but this didn't help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The ScrollViewer in WinRT is optimized for performance and uses DirectManpulation under the hood. That's why it's tricky to have both scrolling from the ScrollViewer and gestures inside it.

This blog post from Rob Caplan (MS employee) gives more information:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/02/16/where-did-all-my-gestures-go.aspx

> Unfortunately there is no good solution if the app needs both scrolling and gestures (for example, to detect CrossSlides against the scrolling). In this case the only option to get the Pointer messages everywhere is to disable Direct Manipulation everywhere, but that disables scrolling as well. To get that back the app will need to detect the scrolling gestures itself and then navigate the ScrollViewer to the new location with ScrollToHorizontalOffset or ScrollToVerticalOffset or by updating the SelectedIndex. This is tricky and will be noticeably slower than letting the ScrollViewer do its thing. It should be avoided if at all possible.

Hope this helps